# How to Override LongPress in ListFragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a ListFragment Activity.

I want to create a method for onItemClickedLongPress, so that when the user does this. a menu pops up. I am familiar with creating the menu.

So if some one would please, give me further instructions on how to set Override the longpress in a ListFragment activity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edit: this sample shows how to show something other then system menu fx. QuickAction from https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //.......
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo amenuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    Object item = getListAdapter().getItem(amenuInfo.position);
    //item could be Cursor/String/YourObject it depends on Adapter
    //show popup fx. QuickAction from https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction
    QuickAction qa = new QuickAction(getActivity());
    qa.setAnimStyle(QuickAction.ANIM_AUTO);
    qa.show(amenuInfo.targetView);
}
```

**EDIT:
This ansewer is not good** ... why i did this such strange method? because eclipse intellisense did not propmt "good" `setOnLongClickListener` for `ListView` (since `ListView` has at least 2 `setOnLongClickListener` methods ... one from `View` and second from `AdapterView` class) ... the easiest way is let your `ListFragment` implement `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` and then in `onViewCreated` add code `getListView().setOnLongClickListener(this);`

Comment: menuInfo is null ? what to do now ?

Answer (score 5):

By "long press", I think you are referring to the context menu.  For a `ListFragment`, all you should have to do is to register for the context menu:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle icicle) {    
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
```

Once you do that, the `ListFragment` should call `onCreateContextMenu()` and `onContextItemSelected()` when it detects a long press.

Answer (score 0):

Modified Erich Douglass' answer further.. for some reason my own app would crash until I modified my code and placed the registration into onViewCreated as follows:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Show your popout menu here.
    }
});
```